# How can I save a file with many histograms using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, file-io, computer-vision, histogram

I`m using the OpenCV framework and I need save many histograms in a file to recover it later. Together with the histogram I need save a Id to each one.

What is the best way to do this using the OpenCv with C++?

Thanks,

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a format of your own. 
Just write functions to read from that format and write to that format.
For example: You have a text file, you saved all the data of histogram in that text file along with ID. 
So, you just need a way to read that data from the text file.